# Reheating popcorn

Tags: temperature, snack-food

I'm talking about real popcorn made in pot, not microwave popcorn in a bag.

I like warm popcorn, but sometimes I have too much and I don't want to throw it away so I keep it, but I want to reheat it.

I've tried microwave it but it comes up dry and kills it.

***Life hack needed.***

Comment: I have found that popcorn gets "stale" or something after just 30 minutes. I'll be interested to read any answers to this question.

Comment: Why is this tagged "snack-food"? I eat little else.

Answer (score 2):

**Please see the below steps which I always do when I want to reheat the popcorn. With below steps popcorn never burn and it cost nothing because all the things are available in everyone's home.**

> 1. Heat the deep frying pan or any pan you have and just put it on gas stove and start heating that pan for sometime. [ Note: I guess 3-4
>      minutes is enough ]
> 2. Now if you feel that the pan is hot enough close the gas stove.
> 3. Now put all the popcorn inside that pan and put lid on it. If you do not have lid than use any kind of plate.
> 4. Now open the lid or plate and its done with hot popcorn.

[image: Popcorn inside hot deep frying pan]

Comment: I've never tried any of these but this answer is very promising as it should stop the popcorn from getting too dry, as the small vessel with the lid on should stop most of the water vapour from escaping. However could you please clarify some points: 1.  How do you tell the pan is hot enough before you turn off the heat?  2. For how long do you leave the popcorn in the pot? Taking the lid off all the time to check doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: @Flint 1. Pan is hot enough means For E.g. You start heating the empty pan for 4 minutes so the pan is heated enough. If your pan is not hot enough then your popcorn not going to hot enough so it is very important to pan is hot enough. 2. No you don't need to check every time. Just put your popcorn and put the lid and rest them for 4-5 minutes then open the lid and put them out from bowl.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can put popcorn in a vessel/utensil.
2. Put this utensil in a water bath and boil it for some time.
3. Shake the popcorn, turn them upside down and heat some more.

I'm not sure how long it will take to warm the popcorn properly, but this trick should ensure that they don't taste stale.

Answer (score 1):

Movie theaters use hot air to keep popcorn warm and to warm it up the next day.  Try a hair dryer, but make sure the container is closed enough that it doesn't blow out.

Answer (score -1):

Put a blowtorch approximately a meter under the pan (the height may vary depending on how strong the blowtorch is)